# Как передать в функцию параметр id в js

Tags: javascript, dom

Есть функция меняющая значение id-блока на "block", изначально он скрыт, значение none

```
function show(p) 
{
document.getElementById("p").style.display = "block";
}
```

Проблема в том, что значение меняется, если вместо p напрямую написать id-блока("name2"), можно ли его как-нибудь передать в функцию и благополучно использовать?

Сам вызов функции

```
<p onclick="show("name2")">Пример текста</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что у Вас некорректный HTML и из-за этого не срабатывает событие `onclick`:

```
<p onclick="show("name2")">Пример текста</p>
```

Кавычки надо экранировать.
Просто приведу корректные варианты:

```
<p onclick="show(\"name2\")">Пример текста</p>
<p onclick="show('name2')">Пример текста</p>
<p onclick='show("name2")'>Пример текста</p>
<p onclick='show(\'name2\')'>Пример текста</p>
```

Наиболее удобной практикой является в HTML использовать один вид кавычек, а в JavaScript - другой.

После исправления ошибки

```
function show( p ) {
    document.getElementById( p ).style.display = "block";
}
```

успешно будет работать.

---

P.S. Я соврал. Наиболее удобной практикой является "навешивание" событий на элементы разметки. Вроде этого:

```
$( "p" ).on( "click", show );
```

Но это уже потом, когда окончательно разберетесь с основами ;)

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Как только не пробовал передавать параметры, а про экранирование забыл.